# Way to search pdf for annotations, edits and other review markings?

Tags: pdf, evince, okular

**Problem:** When I get a proof-read pdf back, sometimes there is only one mark every ten pages or so - and that mark can be so small (missed comma, etc.) that I might miss it when scanning through for markings and notes.

**Question:** Is there a way to search for or jump through the list of in-line notes, edits, markings etc. that can be added to a pdf with the review tools (e.g. in okular and acrobat)?

I use okular, but am fine using a different viewer (evince, etc.) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In Okular open sidebar, in application toolbar, Settings > Show Sidebar , default keyboard shortcut F7 or at Main Toolbar, find the icon. Sidebar will appear at left side, it contains 3 tab, Thumbnails, Annotations, Bookmarks. 2nd tab is what you want.

[image]